# explanation shell scripting code “ for loop”

Tags: linux, bash

Can anybody explain for me what is this loop using for, or how it works?

```
for file in `ls *SC*`; do 
  for content in `cat $file `; do
    scid=`echo $file|awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
    printf "%-10s%s\n" $scid $content
  done
done > text1
```

Comment: Did you add the `**` at the beginning and end of the code? And is this for bash in Linux?

Comment: no it's without ** sorry my mistake when i change to formate code i click Bold so this apear!

Comment: Ah, ok. You can edit & fix/change it too. And if i'ts only for bash & Linux you don't need all the extra tags, it's not Unix, and shell-script would be redundant

Answer (score -1):

Odd code, will fail if filenames have spaces, and splits up file by spaces.

```
for file in `ls *SC*`; do # parses ls for files with SC in the name
    # - not the best way to do it (don't parse ls, fails if spaces in filename)
  for content in `cat $file `; do # copies file to $content, SEPARATED BY SPACES
    scid=`echo $file|awk -F'.' '{print $1}'` # cuts filename to first .(?)
    printf "%-10s%s\n" $scid $content # prints cut filename + content
  done
done > text1
```